# How to backup created symlinks?

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

I have a number of symlinks created on my Windows 7 system. Is there a way to create a backup of all symlinks so after i reinstall Windows to restore them with one click and not recreate them one by one?

Comment: You can get a [list](http://superuser.com/questions/52852/how-can-i-find-all-symlinks-in-windows-vista-or-7?rq=1) of your current symlinks from that information a simple script you should be easy enough to create.

Answer (score 1):

http://sf.net/projects/junctionbox might be able to do what you need.

dir /al /s will give you a list of the junctions, btw.